# using pygit2 to collect data from github

Tags: python, git

I wish to collect repositories from GitHub using pygit2 but have an issue.
My code:

```
from pygit2 import clone_repository
file = open("data_trim.txt", "r")
count = 1

for line in file:
    repo_path = "repo"+str(count)
    count = count+1
    repo_url = "http://github.com/%s.git"%line
    print repo_url
    repo = clone_repository(repo_url, repo_path)
```

I have this error, "ValueError: Malformed URL 'http://github.com/Elvish-Hunter/wesnoth
.git" when I run the code. I also tried using, (repo_url = "http://github.com"+line+".git") but had the same problem. Any help on how to solve the problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Quite likely you have a `\n` character or similar at the end of each line. You can get around that by doing `line.strip()`.

Comment: 'line.strip()' couldn't work but I have gotten a solution to it using 'line[:-1]'. Thank you for making me to think in that direction. @bernie